# How to use google api like google drive with firebaseUI

Tags: firebaseui

hi i followed the tutorial for Add user auth flow to a Flutter desktop app using FirebaseUI, after that i want to use google apis.

```
Future<void> _createFile() async{
  var httpClient = ???? ;

  final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(httpClient);

  final folder = drive.File()
    ..name = 'My New Folder'
    ..mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder';
  final folderInfo = await driveApi.files.create(folder);

  final list = await driveApi.files.list();
  for (var file in list.files!) {
    print('${file.name})');
  }
  if(list.files!.isEmpty){
    debugPrint("aucun fichier dans le drive");
  }
}
I don't know how to get the httpClient.
```

on android i use

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  ],
);
```

with `var httpClient = (await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient())!;` but it doesn't work on Windows